# Read/Write .string files from/to Directory

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsfilemanager

I have a framework that expects a .string file from the Project that it is imported to. How do I save a .string file from my app's `[NSBundle mainBundle]` to `NSLibraryDirectory`, and then have the framework read it from `NSLibraryDirectory`?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can get path to bundle Directory and Library directory and Move file from bundle to Library directory with `CopyItemAtPath`

```
NSArray *libraryPath=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *directoryPath = [libraryPath objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *imagePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Templete.string"];

// Copy the image Folder from the package to the users filesystem
[fileManager copyItemAtPath:imagePathFromApp toPath:directoryPath error:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @iOS_Developer for the writing part.

```
NSString *resourcepath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"filename.strings"];

NSString *filePath = [kSXBFileManLibraryDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"filename.strings"];
```

Write:

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error;
if ([fileManager copyItemAtPath: resourcepath toPath:destination error:&error]){
    NSLog(@"Copy Success");
}
else{
    NSLog(@"Copy error: %@", error);
}
```

Read:

```
NSString *newPath = [kLibraryDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"filename.strings"];
NSDictionary *contents = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:newPath];
NSLog(@"contents:%@", [contents objectForKey:@"login.background"]);
```

where;

```
#define kLibraryDirectoryPath [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject]
```

filename.strings

```
"login.background"          = "FE8100";
"login.textField"           = "FE8100";
"login.button"              = "1B0D62";
```